# Randomly accessing dictionary string values in a .plist file

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, random, info.plist

I have created a simple dictionary:

```
    let quotes: NSArray = ["hello", "ola", "hi"]
```

Then I randomly access the strings in this dictionary with the following code:

```
    let range: UInt32 = UInt32(quotes.count)
    let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(range))
    let QuoteString = quotes.objectAtIndex(randomNumber)
    self.resultLabel.text = QuoteString as? String
```

Since I would ultimately like aloft of items in my dictionary, I should create a .plist file and called it "Quotes.plist" - it will be easier to manage a dictionary of many strings.

How can I write a simple code so as to randomly access strings within my .plist?

**Amended Code:**

```
func randomWord() -> String? {
        guard let
            path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Quotes", ofType: "plist"),
            words = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String:String] else { return nil }
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(words.values.count)))
        return Array(words.values)[randomIndex]
```

My .plist file is "Quotes.plist".

A simple question (I apologise in advance), but how do I modify `self.resultLabel.text = QuoteString as? String` so that the random quote now appears in my `resultLabel.txt`?

Comment: `quotes` is not an dictionary, its an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IF** your PLIST is defined as a Dictionary then this should do the job. Otherwise please provide mode details about how your PLIST is structured.

```
func randomWord() -> String? {
    guard let
        path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Words", ofType: "plist"),
        words = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String:String] else { return nil }
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(words.values.count)))
    return Array(words.values)[randomIndex]
}
```

Comment: I have amended my code and listed in at the bottom of my initial question above. How can I pull from this new function to display the random quote in my resultLabel.txt outlet?

Comment: Quotes.plist is a dictionary I believe: `<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>New item</key>
 <string>hi</string>
 <key>New item - 2</key>
 <string>ola</string>
 <key>New item - 3</key>
 <string>hello</string>
</dict>
</plist>`

Comment: @PaulSatem: just write `if let randomWord = randomWord() {
    resultLabel.text = randomWord
} else {
    print("Error")
}`

Comment: Ahh! Eureka moment! TYVM.